# JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault not working for empty string

Tags: json, .net-core, webapi

I have have a dotnet core webapi that sometimes has empty strings in the return fields. I dont want to return these to save bandwidth. I have used JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault however the endpoint is still returning fields with empty strings.

Here is the class

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = "";
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Here is the endpoint

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        var people = new List<Person>();

        people.Add(new Person() {PersonId = 1, FirstName = "Joe"});
        people.Add(new Person() {PersonId = 2, MiddleName = "Fred"});
        people.Add(new Person() {PersonId = 3, LastName = "Jim"});

        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(people, new JsonSerializerOptions(){
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
        });
    }
```

Here is what I get back

```
[
  {
    "PersonId": 1,
    "FirstName": "Joe",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": ""
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 2,
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "Fred",
    "LastName": ""
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 3,
    "FirstName": "",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Jim"
  }
]
```

I was expecting

```
[
  {
    "PersonId": 1,
    "FirstName": "Joe"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 2,
    "MiddleName": "Fred"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 3,
    "LastName": "Jim"
  }
]
```

Comment: default value for string type is ``null`` not ``empty``.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]` attribute will fix this. It will ignore the property that could have an empty string value.

Modify your model like :

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("FirstName")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    
    [JsonPropertyName("MiddleName")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = "";
    
    [JsonPropertyName("LastName")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I still get the exact same response after making that change.